# How to find people by email address?

Tags: email

Services like rapportive are able to link an email address with a twitter account and a name. I was wondering how they are doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, after some searching, [rapleaf](http://www.rapleaf.com) seems to provide what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [`user search`](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/search) function in the Twitter API to search for email addresses.

> Runs a search for users similar to
>   Find People button on Twitter.com. The
>   results returned by people search on
>   Twitter.com are the same as those
>   returned by this API request.

Comment: thanks, but I can't see how you can search via email address through that API request.